# Kusto Query Language - Extract all between two Characters

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I'm working on extracting an email address from the additionalextensions column in Sentinel. I've found a regex that works perfectly in a [calculator](https://regex101.com/), extracting everything after a colon (:) up to a semicolon followed by the latter s (;s). However, it does not work in Kusto I suspect because its using a lookback?

Below is the regex that worked in the calculator:

(?<=:).*(?=;s)

This is data from one of the logs:

cat=EXFILTRATION;account=O365:email.address@test.org.uk;start=1659975196000;end=165997519600

When using the calculator, it returns the below:

email.address@test.org.uk

However, when trying to use this in Kusto, it returns the original data. Is anyone able to come up with a way I can achieve this in KQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *extracting everything after a colon (:) up to a semicolon followed by the latter s (;s).*

you don't have to use a regular expression.

for instance, using the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator):

```
print input = 'cat=EXFILTRATION;account=O365:email.address@test.org.uk;start=1659975196000;end=165997519600'
| parse input with * ":" email_address ";s" *
```

| input | email_address |
| --- | --- |
| cat=EXFILTRATION;account=O365:email.address@test.org.uk;start=1659975196000;end=165997519600 | email.address@test.org.uk |